# Iterate through set and continue

Tags: java, iterator

I iterate through a Set.
If a value of a CarDetail is not set i want that the loop starts again with the next CarDetail.
But somehow my continue wont work. Isnt it possible to use a continue with an iterator?

```
final Set<CarDetail> tmpDetail = new HashSet<CarDetail>(details);
   for(Iterator<CarDetail> iter = tmpDetail.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){                       
      CarDetail detail = iter.next();
      if(detail.getBack() == null){
      continue;
   }
   ... do something
}
```

Comment: This is just a For loop. Like any for loop, you can use continue;

Comment: It looks fine to me. Please add information on what exactly is unexpected and how you prove that.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase what you're trying to do? And might I suggest using the enhanced `for` loops? `for(CarDetail detail : iter) {` will do splendidly! Or even better is `for(CarDetail detail : details) {`

Comment: Its difficult to explain, because i got a strange bug, and i thought its coming from this.. but it seems that it isnt.. so i think i can close this thread.. thanks..

Comment: why does he need an iterator?  he can simply for loop through the set

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using continue with iterators. You can even use this with an enhanced for loop (for each loop):

```
final Set<CarDetail> tmpDetail = new HashSet<CarDetail>(details);
for(CarDetail detail : tmpDetail) {                           
      if(detail.getBack() == null) {
         System.out.println("Skipping over " + detail.toString() );
         continue;
      }
      System.out.println("Processing car detail: " + detail.toString() );
     //... do something
}
```

How are you sure that the continue statement is being ignored in the code you posted?
With a few little println statements, we can verify that the continue is working as we expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a `Set` directly without getting an `Iterator` and use `continue` in the loop if you wish.  Here is an example:

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
intSet.add(1);intSet.add(2);intSet.add(3);

for(Integer setElem : intSet)
{
    if(setElem.intValue() == 2) continue;

    System.out.println("Current set element is " + setElem);
}
```

prints only

```
Current set element is 1
Current set element is 3
```

Because there is a `continue` if it is 2.  As there is no guarantee of ordering in a `Set`, the output may well also be

```
Current set element is 3
Current set element is 1
```